# Get first and last entry given a timespan

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am using Kibana to log actions performed by the users of my web interface.

I would like to create a visualisation that does the following:

- For each of my users (I have a field for that in my Elastic entries)
- Display the first and last entry datetime

Maybe should I make two visualisations, on for first, one for last, as I don't know if it possible to do it on one single Visual.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found the answer, in the case of a Data Table visualization, I added two metrics:

The min and max of the datetime field I use as the timestamp.

Changing the timespan of your visualization will give you the first and last entry datetimes.